# Looking for n-th instance of x node in root node

Tags: xpath

Suppose I have following xml

```
<root>
    <x>
        <y />
        <z>
            <y />
        </z>
        <n>
            <m>
                <y />*
            </m>
        </n>
    </x>
    <x>
        <y />
        <z>
            <y />
        </z>
        <y />*
    </x>
</root>
```

I would like to retrieve those y nodes which are followed with *

So it is always third node in x ancestor node

I tried something like:

```
//x//y[3]
```

However it doesn't work I guess it would work only if y nodes are on the same level.

So I tried
`(//x//y)[3]` but it retrieves only one node (third one) in whole document

So I tried something like:

```
//x(//y)[3]
//x(//y[3])
//x//(y[3])
```

etc. but I get parse error

Is there any way to retrieve what I need using xpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
//x/descendant::y[3]
```

This selects every third `y` descendant of each `x` in the document. It sometimes helps to write out an expanded expression to see what's really going on. In this case, the following:

```
//x//y[3]
```

is equivalent to:

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/child::x/descendant-or-self::node()/child::y[3]
```

Written this way it becomes obvious why it doesn't do what you wanted (i.e. it's looking for any `y` that is the third *child* of an `x` element and there isn't one). What you really wanted was every third `y` *descendant*. Here it is fully expanded:

```
/descendant-or-self::node()/child::x/descendant::y[3]
```

The important lesson here is that it pays to know what the XPath [abbreviated syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#path-abbrev) is really doing. The spec is actually quite readable. I recommend taking a look.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: both of these examples are XPath 2.0 only.

<s>In XPath 1.0:</s>

```
/row//y/(ancestor::x//y)[3]
```

In XPath 2.0:

```
for $x in /row//x
return ($x//y)[3]
```

Comment: The XPath 1.0 snippet gives `Invalid expression`

Comment: What XPath engine are you using? I tested the expression in Saxon 9.5, and it worked. It fails in older versions of Saxon, or in Xalan. It's possible that Saxon 9.5 is evaluating the expression as XPath 2.0 ...

Comment: Looks like you are confirming the XPath 1.0 issue. First when I looked into this question it looked like "easy to solve". But, I have only xpath 1.0 and I couldn't find a way... Crazy, didn't expected that! However +1 for your investigations. Could await XPath 2.0 being finally more widely deployed. (or being de-facto standard)